# NextJS not add the width and height properties to image tags

Tags: next.js, seo, nextjs-image

I'm improving my application made in Nextjs, and I started for SEO optimization, [PageSpeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev) recommends adding explicit width and height properties to image tags. When I use the component Image from "next/Image", It returns me the following:

```html
<span style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; overflow: hidden; width: initial; height: initial; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; inset: 0px;">
    <img alt="my-img" sizes="100vw" srcset="/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=640&amp;q=75 640w, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=750&amp;q=75 750w, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=828&amp;q=75 828w, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=1080&amp;q=75 1080w, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=1200&amp;q=75 1200w, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=1920&amp;q=75 1920w, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=2048&amp;q=75 2048w, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75 3840w" src="/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-img.26135ca6.webp&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75" decoding="async" data-nimg="fill" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: auto; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%; object-fit: contain;" />
</span>
```

In NextJS it would be something like:

```html
<Image
  alt="my-img"
  loading="eager"
  layout="fill"
  objectFit="contain"
  src={myImg}
/>
```

Well, I don't add the width and height properties to the Image component, because I need a responsive image. However, if I add the width and height properties, they are not reflected in the "img" tag. Is there a way to display these properties to improve SEO a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Pagespeed does not know your intention of using responsive images. What they have given is a general recommendation but it is not a rule or law.

Often one cannot and should not follow their recommendations. That may make getting a top score impossible but they are asking for the impossible at the same time.

Ignore it.

Comment: hi sir, I really think that PageSpeed is strict, I would like to question you, exist another page for testing the performance of websites?